# Using dynamic regular expression for a string.split() returns an array with undefined elements. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am writing a node module that takes csv file and turns it into a javascript object. Because I am allowing the user to specify the delimiter, and support text qualifiers, I need to parse it with dynamic regex.

Here is how I create the regex:

```
settings.dilemeter = escapeForRegex(settings.dilemeter);


 settings.textQualifier = escapeForRegex(settings.textQualifier);
  var d = settings.dilemeter;
  var tq = settings.textQualifier;

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /// This appears to be glitched
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var searchArray = [
    "(" + tq + d + tq + ")", // First case to search for, eg: ","
    "(" + tq + d + ")", // Second case to search for, eg: ",
    "(" + d + tq + ")", // Third case to search for, eg: ,"
    "(" + d + ")", // Last case to search for, eg: ,
    "(" + tq + "$)", // if the text qualifier is the very last thing
  ];
  var regexString = "(" + searchArray.join('|') + ')';
  console.log(regexString);
  var regex = new RegExp(regexString);
```

Which produces a regular expression that looks like this (when using | and " as dilemeters and text qualifiers) `(("\|")|("\|)|(\|")|(\|)|("$))`

which seems to match strings that I want to match here: [http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=((%22%5C%7C%22)%7C(%22%5C%7C)%7C(%5C%7C%22)%7C(%5C%7C)%7C(%22%24))&input=h1%7Ch2%7Ch3%7Ch4%0Avalue%201%7C%22Value%202%22%7Cvalue%203%7C%22value%20-%205%22%7Csomething%7C%22Else%22](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%28%28%22%5C%7C%22%29%7C%28%22%5C%7C%29%7C%28%5C%7C%22%29%7C%28%5C%7C%29%7C%28%22%24%29%29&input=h1%7Ch2%7Ch3%7Ch4%0Avalue%201%7C%22Value%202%22%7Cvalue%203%7C%22value%20-%205%22%7Csomething%7C%22Else%22)

However, when I run this using `string.split(regex)` I get really strange results.

```
var testString = [
        'h1|h2|h3|h4', // The first line will be the headers
        'value 1|"Value 2"|value 3|"value - 5"'// This is the first row of data
    ];
console.log(testString[1].split(regex));
```

produces:

```
["value 1",
"|"",
undefined,
undefined,
"|"",
undefined,
undefined,
"Value 2",
""|",
undefined,
""|",
undefined,
undefined,
undefined,
"value 3",
"|"",
undefined,
undefined,
"|"",
undefined,
undefined,
"value - 5",
""",
undefined,
undefined,
undefined,
undefined,
""",
""]
```

I can't seem to figure out why there are all of these undefined and why its returning the items that I am trying to split on.

I created a plunker with a more contextually complete demonstration http://plnkr.co/edit/hn2GUFYodYQeuQLqqwVD?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.split(regexp)` returns entries for all the capture groups in the regexp. If you need groups in the regexp, but don't want them to be included in the results, use non-capturing groups. These are denoted by putting `?:` after the opening parenthesis of the group:

```
var searchArray = [
    "(?:" + tq + d + tq + ")", // First case to search for, eg: ","
    "(?:" + tq + d + ")", // Second case to search for, eg: ",
    "(?:" + d + tq + ")", // Third case to search for, eg: ,"
    "(?:" + d + ")", // Last case to search for, eg: ,
    "(?:" + tq + "$)", // if the text qualifier is the very last thing
  ];
var regexString = "(?:" + searchArray.join('|') + ')';
```